# Is it possible to write your processing provider in C++ as a plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, c++, visual-studio

Added a processing provider to his plugin, the plugin stopped downloading. Maybe c++ cannot be created at all.

**plugin.cpp**

```
void MyPlugins::initGui()
{
    initProcessing();
}

void MyPlugins::initProcessing()
{

    processing_provider = new MyProvider(QgsApplication::processingRegistry());
    bool ok = QgsApplication::processingRegistry()->addProvider(processing_provider);
    if(!ok) {
        ErrorViewer::ShowError("Don't add provider");
    }
}
```

**myprovider.h**

```
class MyProvider: public QgsProcessingProvider {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyProvider(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QIcon icon() const override;
    QString svgIconPath() const override;
    QString id() const override;
    QString helpId() const override;
    QString name() const override;
    bool supportsNonFileBasedOutput() const override;

protected:
    void loadAlgorithms() override;
};
```

**myprovider.cpp**

```
MyProvider::MyProvider(QObject *parent)
    : QgsProcessingProvider(parent)
{
}

QIcon MyProvider::icon() const
{

    return QgsApplication::getThemeIcon(QStringLiteral("/providerQgis.svg"));
}

QString MyProvider::svgIconPath() const
{

    return QgsApplication::iconPath(QStringLiteral("providerQgis.svg"));
}

QString MyProvider::id() const
{
    return QStringLiteral("myprovider");
}

QString MyProvider::name() const
{
    return tr("MyProvider");
}

QString MyProvider::helpId() const
{
    return tr("MyProvider");
}

bool MyProvider::supportsNonFileBasedOutput() const
{
    return true;
}

void MyProvider::loadAlgorithms()
{
    const QgsScopedRuntimeProfile profile(QObject::tr("MyProvider"));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "downloading"? Do you get errors on stderr?

Comment: @bugmenot123 the plugin simply does not appear in the list of plugins. As if it does not exist. If you remove the creation of MyProvider, the plugin is displayed. It’s as if qgis does some sort of dll check and doesn’t load it. It may not be possible to create a custom processing provider on c++. But the api says it should work.

Comment: Are you sure that you implemented all necessary methods in the plugin.cpp class?

Comment: @bugmenot123 of cource.... I just didn’t show them all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In QGIS 3.30.3 does not work custom gptools, updated version to 3.32, it's work.